# What is the right usage of the word chance in this context

Tags: usage

“Many desired the (blank) with like-minded individuals .”

A)chance connecting

B)chance to connect

C)connection chance

D)chance for the connection

I think choice B is the right one but still can’t figure out why others are wrong. The verb desire needs a noun after it and all choices offer a noun so how could they be wrong ?
Thank you

Comment: I agree that B is the right choice. The word *chance* needs an infinitive, not a gerund, so A is out. C just sounds clumsy, though it might be understood. D would work, but it would be better as "chance for **a** connection", since the connection doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Option B - 'chance to connect' is the most idiomatic in your example.

Remember that 'chance' has many different meanings. As a noun, it can mean *opportunity* (eg 'an opportunity to connect'), which is what your example requires.

As an adjective, 'chance' means *by accident or random occurrence* (eg 'a chance meeting'), so option A is incorrect because of this latter meaning - it sounds like a random connection.

'Chance' can also refer to a *measure of probability*, which is why option C  is wrong - it sounds like you are referring to how likely a connection is.

Option D isn't wrong - just not idiomatic.